# Using NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection, need to relaunch Mac app to convert app from LTR to RTL

Tags: swift, macos, localization, arabic-support

In my Mac OSX app I want to change app from LTR to RTL when user uses Arabic language, without changing the system language.

I have used the below code to make my Mac OSX app appear LTR to RTL for arabic Localization.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"AppleTextDirection"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection"];
```

It works, but I need to restart the app, to see the change.

Is there any way, we can change app from LTR to RTL without restarting the app?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize your UserDefaults before and then get resources by code language you want finally associate it with the main bundle:

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: LANGUAGE_CODE, ofType: "lproj") else {
            print("Failed to get a bundle path.")
            return
        }
objc_setAssociatedObject(Bundle.main, SAFE_KEY, Bundle(path: path), objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
```

Comment: But this only change the language not the Direction. I want my app's app objects to appear in Right to Left instead of Left to Right as it works when you change your system langauge.

Comment: Ah oki, so you need to update semanticContentAttribute
use Locale.characterDirection(forLanguage: SELECTEED_LANGUAGE_CODE) that return direction of selected language then semanticContentAttribute
Exam;ple : 
let isLanguageRTL = Locale.characterDirection(forLanguage: SELECTED_LANGUAGE_CODE) == .rightToLeft
 UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = isLanguageRTL ? .forceRightToLeft : .forceLeftToRight

Comment: semanticContentAttribute is used for iOS & Mac catalyst. Which is not useful for me as I am not using Mac catalyst.